# Solr 5.3.1 - Db-import-hander - TikaEntityProcessor Cannot Find My http files

Tags: solr, apache-tika

My table has a reference URL as a column of a file, along with the other columns. Sample table as follows, I'm trying to index the table along with the file content in SOLR. The files are accessible via URL with 'http://domain.com/' prefix eg., 'http://domain.com/file/sample1.pdf'. And I will not be able to access these files as fileshares.

```
Filepath                author   Title
file/sample1.pdf        Jack     title 1
file/sample2.pdf        Bob      title 2
file/sample3.docx       Tim      title 2
```

My db-data-import xml is something like this,

```
<dataConfig>
    <dataSource name="dbrows" driver="oracle.jdbc.OracleDriver" 
                url="jdbc:oracle:thin:@..... 
                user="***"
                password="***"/>    
    <dataSource type="BinFileDataSource" name="attachments" />

    <document>
        <entity name="docs"  dataSource="dbrows" query="select 'http://domain.com/'||filepath as PATH,author,title from dummytable" >           

        <entity name="file"
                processor="TikaEntityProcessor"
                url="${docs.PATH}"
                dataSource="attachments"
                format="text"
                onError="continue"
                transformer="script:processFile">
          <field column="text" name="text" />
          </entity>  
        </entity>
    </document>
</dataConfig>
```

The error i'm getting is,

```
2015-10-13 23:15:43.859 WARN  (Thread-25) [   x:db] o.a.s.h.d.FileDataSource FileDataSource.basePath is empty. Resolving to: C:\Users\asdf\Downloads\Solr\solr-5.3.1\server\.
2015-10-13 23:15:43.860 ERROR (Thread-25) [   x:db] o.a.s.h.d.EntityProcessorWrapper Exception in entity : file:java.lang.RuntimeException: java.io.FileNotFoundException: Could not find file: http://domain.com/file/sample1.pdf (resolved to: C:\Users\asdf\Downloads\Solr\solr-5.3.1\server\.\http://domain.com/file/sample1.pdf
    at org.apache.solr.handler.dataimport.FileDataSource.getFile(FileDataSource.java:126)
    at org.apache.solr.handler.dataimport.BinFileDataSource.getData(BinFileDataSource.java:51)
    at org.apache.solr.handler.dataimport.BinFileDataSource.getData(BinFileDataSource.java:42)
    at org.apache.solr.handler.dataimport.TikaEntityProcessor.nextRow(TikaEntityProcessor.java:131)
    at org.apache.solr.handler.dataimport.EntityProcessorWrapper.nextRow(EntityProcessorWrapper.java:243)
    at org.apache.solr.handler.dataimport.DocBuilder.buildDocument(DocBuilder.java:475)
    at org.apache.solr.handler.dataimport.DocBuilder.buildDocument(DocBuilder.java:514)
    at org.apache.solr.handler.dataimport.DocBuilder.buildDocument(DocBuilder.java:414)
    at org.apache.solr.handler.dataimport.DocBuilder.doFullDump(DocBuilder.java:329)
    at org.apache.solr.handler.dataimport.DocBuilder.execute(DocBuilder.java:232)
    at org.apache.solr.handler.dataimport.DataImporter.doFullImport(DataImporter.java:416)
    at org.apache.solr.handler.dataimport.DataImporter.runCmd(DataImporter.java:480)
    at org.apache.solr.handler.dataimport.DataImporter$1.run(DataImporter.java:461)
Caused by: java.io.FileNotFoundException: Could not find file: http://domain.com/file/sample1.pdf (resolved to: C:\Users\asdf\Downloads\Solr\solr-5.3.1\server\.\http://domain.com/file/sample1.pdf
    at org.apache.solr.handler.dataimport.FileDataSource.getFile(FileDataSource.java:122)
    ... 12 more

2015-10-13 23:15:43.890 WARN  (Thread-25) [   x:db] o.a.s.h.d.FileDataSource FileDataSource.basePath is empty. Resolving to: C:\Users\asdf\Downloads\Solr\solr-5.3.1\server\.
```

Is this even possible? Any help is highly appreciated.

Answer (score 2):

Fixed. Used BinURLDataSource instead of BinFileDataSource

```
<dataSource type="BinFileDataSource" name="attachments" />
```

changed this to

```
<dataSource type="BinURLDataSource" name="attachments" />
```